# Carriage return doesn't maintain new cursor position

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Running the following simple loop:

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

for ii in range(30):
    sleep(.05)
    if ii % 5 == 0:
        stdout.write('\rReading... %d|' % ii)
    else:
        stdout.write('%d|' % ii)
```

I expected the output to reset like

```
Reading... 0|1|2|3|4|
# reset
Reading... 5|6|7|8|9
# reset
Reading... 10|11|12|13|14
# ...
```

But instead, it seems after the initial carriage return, the cursor is returned to the end of the text on the current line:

```
Reading... 25||2|3|4|6|7|8|9|11|12|13|14|16|17|18|19|21|22|23|24|26|27|28|29|
```

This appears to be a function of the `sleep` time, since setting the wait time to `.05` actually works (you can see the output updating as you run the code):

```
Reading... 25|26|27|28|29|
```

What's going on here? It appears to be Jupyter-specific since neither of the above occur when I run interactively in a `python3` terminal session (no idea where the `14`/`15` and `|2`/`|3` are coming from...):

```
Reading... 0|14
1|2
2|2
3|2
4|2
Reading... 5|14
6|2
7|2
8|2
9|2
Reading... 10|15
11|3
12|3
13|3
14|3
Reading... 15|15
16|3
17|3
18|3
19|3
Reading... 20|15
21|3
22|3
23|3
24|3
Reading... 25|15
26|3
27|3
28|3
29|3
```

Comment: How about `stdout.write('\nReading... %d|' % ii)`? this will give u expected result. For the first empty line, you can just start of the loop and print like `stdout.write('Reading... %d|' % ii)`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between them is that regular python stdout is `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>` while jupyter's is `<class 'ipykernel.iostream.OutStream'>`, therefore the behavior will be different.

You can check where the stream is directed with `isatty()`:

On jupyter it will return `False`, where in regular python - `True`.

The problem is that in jupyter all output is displayed asynchronously, therefore you might need either synchronize it with `flush` or import

```
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
```

And call it manually to implement progress bar.

Comment: OK, makes sense. This script is one that is being tested in Jupyter but ultimately run as a script... how could I go about making the output match in both circumstances?

Comment: I would do something like:
```python
def print_line(string):
    if stdout.isatty():
        stdout.write(string)
        stdout.flush()
    else:
        clear_output()
        print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a buffering problem. There are a couple of options to try:

- Call `stdout.flush()` manually.
- Set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable prior to running the notebook.
- Use `print()` with `flush=True` instead of `stdout.write()`, if you are on Python 3.3+.